# Exchange traffic b/w 3 security groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud

I have 3 security groups. 1st security group "VPN security group", which I am referring in another security group calling it "private security group" and furthermore I am referring the "private security group" in "RDS security group"

I am unable to connect to the database through the "VPN security group" through the above setting.

But when I am referring the "VPN security group" directly in the "RDS security group" I can access the database.

Please let me know why the above setting is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there is no transitivity between security groups. This means that when you accept traffic from "private security group" you are not accepting traffic from all the inbounds in "VPN security group". The only way is to reference "VPN security group" directly in "RDS security group".

Comment: just for clarification, how is it different from the flow ELB>>EC2>>RDS. We use the security groups in this flow as well and it works. Please let me know as I am new to AWS.

Comment: It is possible because the security groups are attached to resources  that process the traffic. ELB is accepting traffic and routing it to your EC2, the EC2 then process the traffic and connects to RDS. The security groups does not do this on their own, they are just virtual firewalls.